# Views in MySQL based on multiple computed values

Tags: mysql

In a follow-up to a previous question, let's say I have 3 tables, A, B, and C. Table A has an ID which is used as a foreign key on tables B and C, each of which has some value as an attribute. For each ID in table A, I want to get the difference in value between tables B and C, which can be done as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW T1 AS
    SELECT B.A_ID AS ID, SUM(B.VALUE) AS VAL
    FROM B
    GROUP BY B.A_ID;
CREATE VIEW T2 AS
    SELECT C.A_ID AS ID, SUM(C.VALUE) AS VAL
    FROM C
    GROUP BY C.A_ID;
SELECT T1.ID, T1.VAL, T2.VAL FROM T1, T2 WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID;
```

The problem is, what if table B has some values for a particular ID, but table C does not, or vice versa. In that case, my select statement will not return that row. Is there a way for me to create a single view, which essentially looks like the following:

```
CREATE VIEW T3 AS
    SELECT B.A_ID AS ID, SUM(B.VALUE) AS VAL1, SUB(C.VAL) AS VAL2
    FROM B, C
    WHERE B.A_ID = C.A_ID
    GROUP BY B.A_ID;
```

An example of the creation script for such a view would be appreciated.

Comment: I am really interested in the solution that ended up working for you.

Comment: I will likely try, at least, using the one you proposed. I'm having an issue with my hosting provider with my user access to the databases that is being resolved, so I have not yet been able to test it, although I have my scripts prepared. If your solution works, I will accept your answer as correct.

Comment: It turns out that my hosting provider only supports MySQL 5.0, and views were introduced in MySQL 5.0.1, so this option for collating the data automatically is out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
CREATE VIEW myView AS
SELECT test_a.id, name, IFNULL( (
  SELECT SUM( value ) 
  FROM test_b
  WHERE test_b.a_id = test_a.id
  GROUP BY test_b.a_id ) , 0
) - IFNULL( (
  SELECT SUM( value ) 
  FROM test_c
  WHERE test_c.a_id = test_a.id
  GROUP BY test_c.a_id ) , 0
)
FROM test_a
```

But this will result in negative numbers if c has a higher sum than b. If you want the absolute difference than use this:

```
CREATE VIEW myView AS
SELECT test_a.id, name, ABS( IFNULL( (
  SELECT SUM( value ) 
  FROM test_b
  WHERE test_b.a_id = test_a.id
  GROUP BY test_b.a_id ) , 0 ) - IFNULL( (
SELECT SUM( value ) 
  FROM test_c
  WHERE test_c.a_id = test_a.id
  GROUP BY test_c.a_id ) , 0
  )
)
FROM test_a
```

Comment: Considering that both tables B and C have potentially thousands of rows, for hundreds of rows in A, what would the performance of this query be? (I would use the first option, as I need to know if the difference is positive or negative.) Also, is there a way to do this as a view?

Comment: to create a view just add

CREATE VIEW viewName AS in front of the query...

as far as performance I don't know... you'll have to try it... I just set up three tables with a few rows each.

Another issue to consider is if there is an ID in table a that is not in either b or c... my queries will return 0. If you don't want this, there are ways around it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, MAX(VAL1), MAX(VAL2) FROM 
((SELECT B.A_ID AS ID, SUM(B.VALUE) AS VAL1, 0 as VAL2
FROM B GROUP BY B.A_ID) as T1
UNION
(SELECT C.A_ID AS ID, 0 VAL1, SUM(C.VALUE) AS VAL2
FROM C GROUP BY C.A_ID) as T2) as Foo
GROUP BY FOO.ID
```

Its a bit hacky. Plus, you can't create a view that has a union.